# Is there a way to make a skill autocast-able?

Tags: dota-2

So I was playing a bit of Bristleback, and after it got to late game, as it does, and I got an octarine core, with more mana than I could spend, I was pressing w to walk.

After that game, and a certain amount of hand cramp, I was wondering if there was a way, a console command possibly to make an ability able to be autocast?

I have a feeling the answer's no, as I vaguely remember autocast being added to specific spells in patches, but if you don't ask, you don't find out.

Comment: upvoted for the line in the end and for good question..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not possible. at present the only autocastable ability are :

- Manually castable Unique Attack Modifier like Drow's Frost Arrow or Viper's Poison Attack
- Lich's Frost Armor
- Ogre Magi's BloodLust
- Troll Priest's (neutral) heal

You can however set a macro (on your mouse/keyboard) to press the key every x.xx sec depending on the spell.

Comment: Good workaround, and nice summary. I'll leave it for a bit, but if nothing better comes up, I'm happy to accept this.

Comment: You can add OD orb, Hushkar fire arrows, Clinks fire arrows, Silencer glaives and Enchantress ultimate.

Comment: Also you can add big troll raise corpses.

Comment: @zozo OD arcane orb and so on are mentionned in the first point as Unique Attack Modifier. DarkTroll summoner's raising corpse ability has been removed from autocasting ability in dota 2

Comment: Well... seems I am a dinosaur :)). Should start playing again a bit.

Comment: Don't forget zakiro too.